# Finding pair of integers with given modulo

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computational-complexity

Given integer Goal and S = { X0, X1, ...., Xn } where Xi is a positive integer > 1, find a, b, in S and positive integer n (not necessarily in S) such that:

a*n mod b = Goal

E.g. Goal = 1, S = {3, 5}, solved by a=3, b=5, n=2:

3*2 mod 5 = 1

I'm trying to write a program to solve* this, but an exhaustive search seems impractical as S can be large (say 10k items) and Xi is a 32-bit integer (I have to account for overflow). I'm looking for an efficient way to solve this.

Note: * I recognize that some sets S will have no solution as the first answer below states.  So more completely stated I am trying to build an algorithm that will either solve it, or report there is no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $G = 1$, $S = \{2, 4, 6, \ldots\}$. Let $a, b \in S$. If you multiply $a$ by any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then it is still even and, moreover, $an \pmod{b}$ will be even (with slight abuse of terminology). Therefore you won't be able to solve the congruence equation
\begin{equation}
an \equiv G \pmod{b}.
\end{equation}

You might want to impose some admissibility properties on $S$.

I think you should get a solution whenever $\gcd(a, b)$ divides $G$. I don't know if calculating greatest common divisors is fast enough for you but once you've got those two elements then I'm not sure how to quickly get the value of $n$. It might be fruitful looking at the additive order but I'm not sure. I'll keep thinking.

Comment: Sorry, misread multiplication for exponentiation originally, this still works though.

Comment: Yes that's true, there will be cases where there is no solution. What I'm trying to build is a program that will classify S as having a solution or not.  I will clarify my question.

Comment: Ah ok, I've got a condition but I can't think how best to find $n$, in particular.

Comment: I've done some more research.  You are correct that gcd(a,b) must divide G for a solution to exist.  My old number theory book has some algorithms that describe ways to solve this kind of congruence by reducing the congruence step to step to find n. My math is a bit rusty so I haven't turned it into a coded solution yet.  but I'm on the right track.